# Spring OAuth redirect URL confusion

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm currently following this guide to building a auth service in Spring boot https://www.callicoder.com/spring-boot-security-oauth2-social-login-part-1/

I've modified it so when a user creates and account with a username and password it also returns a refresh_token.

However, when I do an Auth flow with lets say facebook or google, I see the access token is appended in a redirect URL ([see here github link](https://github.com/callicoder/spring-boot-react-oauth2-social-login-demo/blob/00fb4b4607b808819e621da35b35aea9566be8df/spring-social/src/main/java/com/example/springsocial/security/oauth2/OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler.java#L66))

Now reading the [OAuth doc](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/redirect-uris/#:%7E:text=Redirect%20URLs%20are%20a%20critical,access%20token%20in%20the%20URL.) this seems to make sense. However, how do I return the refresh token to the user as well. Is it safe to pass both access and refresh token in the URL?

This is a side project that me and my mate are working on (he's doing the front end which he hasnt started yet :D) so I'm curious if its 1) ok to put both tokens in the URL and 2) should I be setting these as cookies httpOnly somehow for him.

Comment: After further reading. should the redirect actually just contain a grant code which is then used by the client to get an access token / refresh token via a different endpoint?

Comment: Can you add the gihub link to your repo? It is mentioned but not present. Thanks

Comment: Ah sorry, updated now with the link. Thank you for having a look btw

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I'm writing an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return refresh token in the url as well. Other possible solution is to write both tokens in the response body as a JSON payload.

Regarding your other question, you can safely store the refresh tokens in a HttpOnly cookie since it is the recommended way for persisting sensitive session-related data.

Comment: Thank you for the response Santiago, do you know is though, is passing both tokens in the URL any kind of security risk? Also is this a standard way to do it? Or is there another type of OAuth flow I should be using like Authorization Code Grant Type

Comment: Regarding the security risk, not as far as I am concerned but I may need to do more research. Using Spring Social this is the way to go due to the redirect. Using the default login approach, you should add the refresh token and the grant type and other useful data like expiration time to the authentication response payload.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Why would adding grant_type be of any use btw in the response.

Comment: It's a recommended practice for the authorization flow. Sometimes it's useful to have that data on the frontend.

Comment: Cool thanks for the info! You've been so helpful! One last question if I may. Is there any good guide to doing Social login with grant_type?